# .htaccess is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have started working with codeigniter and wanted to remove `index.php` in the URL `/testing_palace/index.php/home` to `/testing_palace/home`, working in localhost.

I google'ed the problem and tried the solutions suggested but didn't worked for me.

I changed `base_url` and index page in config to

```
$config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/testing_palace/';
$config['index_page'] ="";
```

And checked `mod_rewrite` on windows apache is enabled.

Here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testing_palace

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

All these solutions is not working for me getting not found Error.

[image: not found error in codeigniter]

Comment: You missed a slash in your rule, it should be `RewriteBase /testing_palace/`

Comment: Thank you for your response, i tried its not working for me.

Comment: @Mohit Jain i checked mod_rewrite is enabled and followed the steps you have given its not working for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `/testing_palace/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /testing_palace/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

then in `/testing_palace/application/config/config.php` you need to have these config settings:

```
$config['base_url']  = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: I tried its not working...My htaccess file path testing_palace/application/.htaccess

Comment: Above .htaccess I suggested should be placed in `/testing_palace/.htaccess` not in `/testing_palace/application/`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I think it will help you.